# Windows 1 second precise time sync

Tags: windows, datetime

I have database and application servers of my web application running on different windows systems. I want these two server clocks to be in sync on 1 second threshold. First I thought of using w32time of windows but later I found that it does not guarantee that precision.

What is best way to achieve it?

Comment: As long as both servers are regularly synchronized to a reliable NTP server, the time difference between them will be well under 1 second.

Comment: @Sneftel I observed that but I read on many blogs that w32time was developed to support Kerberos which only requires sync up to 5 min so it only guarantees that much sync. Here is blog I referred [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2007/10/23/high-accuracy-w32time-requirements.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Domain Time II (https://www.greyware.com/software/domaintime/) can be very effective at synchronising windows clocks. Its might be overkill for what you need - as others said any basic NTP synchronisation should be able to achieve 1s synch - and Domain Time II aims to do a lot better than that.

However the usual windows tools are a bit tricky to setup and monitor - whereas DTII takes care of everything for you and has nice tools for monitoring/alerting.